# Redistricting algorithm

Tags: algorithms

Here in the USA there is a lot of controversy over the practice of gerrymandering. Every ten years the states are divided up into new congressional districts and whoever is in charge creates bizarrely shaped districts to suit their own political ends.

So the question is -- is there an algorithm to optimize, or at least automate, this process?

Express it like this:

Given a flat plane of pixels, where each pixel has a weight, divide the plane up into n polygons such that the sum of the weights of pixels in each polygon have the same value within a tolerance of k%, such that the total number of sides to all the polygons is as small as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and no.

France is divided into administrative regions, which are divided into departments, which are divided into communes. These boundaries were redrawn during the French Revolution.

This was one proposal for the department boundaries for Metropolitan France (which is the part of France in Europe excluding Corsica), from September 1789:

[image: Geometrical proposal]

Now clearly this doesn't respect population density, but the point that I want to make is that if you value minimising the number of sides of a polygon, this is what you're going to get.

If you do respect population density but still try to minimise the boundary, what you tend to end up with is a Voronoi tessellation around population centres.

Looking at a modern map, you can see that this geometric proposal was rejected in favour of boundaries that follow naturally-occurring boundaries (e.g. rivers, mountain ranges, perhaps major roads), that respect existing means of travel (e.g. public transport routes), and at least try to take into account shared community interest where practical.

So at the very least, it would seem to make more sense not to draw boundaries in arbitrary places, but to start with existing political administrative boundaries, such as suburbs, city limits, postal areas, and cadastral boundaries, and merge them using a clustering algorithm, with some combined weight that involves both the importance of natural boundaries (e.g. a large river weighs more highly than a minor road), and some notion of compactness. There are several well-defined measures of [compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_measure_of_a_shape), such as the area of the shape expressed as a proportion of a circle with the same perimeter.

Ultimately, drawing electoral district boundaries is a political process, not an algorithmic one. Australia has [one of the most open processes for redistribution](https://www.aec.gov.au/electorates/Redistributions/steps.htm) (which is their term for "redistricting"). It involves several steps of community consultation, and requires the reasoning behind proposed boundaries to be published.

Ultimately, the best protection against gerrymandering is probably that: transparency and community consultation.